# javascript Shuffle DIV's within DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am working on a new Website and we want to shuffle a set of DIV Elements within a Document with a specific Class Shuffle:

```
(function($){

$.fn.shuffle = function() {

    var allElems = this.get(),
        getRandom = function(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        },
        shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
            var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
            allElems.splice(random, 1);
            return randEl;
       });

    this.each(function(i){
        $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
    });

    return $(shuffled);

};

})(jQuery);
```

My DIV Elements look like this:

```
<div class="row animate-in shuffle" data-anim-type="fade-in-up">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="team-wrapper">
                    <div class="team-inner" style="background-image: url('assets/img/team/1.jpg')">
                        <!-- <a href="#" target="_blank" > <i class="fa fa-twitter" ></i></a> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h3> Test User 1</h3>
                        <h5><strong> Tester - Inhaber </strong></h5>
                        <p>
                            fon: 1234567890<br>
                            <a href="mailto:test@test.de">e-mail: test@test.de</a><br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="team-wrapper">
                    <div class="team-inner" style="background-image: url('assets/img/team/2.jpg')">
                        <!-- <a href="#" target="_blank" > <i class="fa fa-twitter" ></i></a> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h3> Test User 2</h3>
                        <h5><strong> Tester </strong></h5>
                        <p>
                            fon: 0987654321<br>
                            <a href="mailto:tester2@test.de">e-mail: tester2@test.de</a><br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

This is what i call when the site is loaded:

```
$('div#shuffle div').shuffle();
```

The Elements are still arraged in the same way as they are writen in the Document. Where is my error here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `$('div#shuffle div').shuffle();` seems to be targeting a div with the ID of `shuffle`, however `shuffle` is a class in your HTML. Try `$('div.shuffle div')` instead maybe?

Comment: There are certain downsides to cloning elements such as losing handlers so you really cannot take this approach when shuffling. I am going to give you an example on how to do it, but i will use a simplified version and it is up to you to learn from it and implement it. Posted as answer.

Comment: and you definitely don't want to shuffle `.shuffle div` with this markup, more like `.shuffle>div`. *tiny change, major difference*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example of how to solve the issue. 
Learn from it and implement in your own situation.

[FIDDLEJS](https://jsfiddle.net/6dw04taL/26/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="shuffleMe"> DIV 1</div>
  <div class="shuffleMe"> DIV 2</div>
  <div class="shuffleMe"> DIV 3</div>
  <div class="shuffleMe"> DIV 4</div>
  <div class="shuffleMe"> DIV 5</div>
  <div class="shuffleMe"> DIV 6</div>
</div>
<button onclick="shuffle()">
  SHUFFLE
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function shuffle() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var elementsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(container.getElementsByClassName('shuffleMe'));
    elementsArray.forEach(function(element){
    container.removeChild(element);
  })
  shuffleArray(elementsArray);
  elementsArray.forEach(function(element){
  container.appendChild(element);
})
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: This works for 1 Element with id="container" which is always the first one returned. How do i do it with a class of elements?

Comment: Same thing, you select all elements, convert to array, and forEach it. Pretty much you do what I did for "shuffle" elements to the container as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array with all the elements and then render them in a separate function. At this point you just need to shuffle the array with something that looks like this:

```
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length; i; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
    }
}
```

And re-render the parent div.